# How to center and overlay mask an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I both horizontally and vertically center an image and mask it with thin black overlay? Something like this:

[image]

Here's my attempt:

```html
      <a href="/to" class="link">
        <img src="/a.png">
        <span class="mask" />
      </a>
```

```css
.link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But it does not work, https://ibb.co/NyWgdGY.

Comment: `But it does not work` That's a very vague statement, What exactly doesn't work ? And if you could put up a working snippet illustrating the issue.

Comment: This is what mine looks like: https://ibb.co/NyWgdGY

Comment: why you use `positon:absolute;` ? you need to `positon:realtive;` it's parent

Comment: you can use  `z-index` .

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahAlNoor It works now.

Comment: @Rario Adding `position: relative` only did not work because you also need to specify `width` and `height` as @AbdullahAlNoor made. You wont ever be able to apply to a child `width: 100%` if parent has `width : 0`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Yes, I did.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor 's code has errors. See my answer . I've mentioned the other errors in your markup there.

Comment: @Becky it's not about error .. you use pseudo element and i use span element ... it's trick.. answer should be relevant to the question

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor read my answer. I have mentioned it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things.

1. `<span>` should have a closing tag. The correct way is `<span></span>`
2. You can use the `::before` psudo element to create the mask. So the code is shorter and cleaner. Here's a **[jsFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5afeu3p9/1/)**

```css
.link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.link::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); // Try changing the 0.5 (e.g. 0.4)
}
```

```html
<a href="/to" class="link">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
    
}
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
   background: #ddd;
   opacity: .5;
   
}
```

```html
 <a href="/to" class="link">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
        <span class="mask" > </span>
      </a>
```